# How to prevent duplicate name in Database but same person can take two courses

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am creating one full stack by using MERN(MongoDB, Express, React js and Node). currently, I am working on my backend. I am using REST API and for testing the HTTP request I am using Postman. My goal is, where a student can take multiple lessons. For example: Gymnastics 1, fiteness and so on course.

I created two tables. One is a student table and another one is a course table. I made the relationship between the two tables. But the problem is when I add new data with the same person name and details it shows another dataset. I don't how to prevent duplicate name data.

My goal is like this:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Anni Anonen",
      "birthday": "1992-02-28",
      "address": "Kivakatu 1",
      "zipcode": "00500",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358506760702",
      "email": "anni.anonen@testing.fi",
      "courses": [1]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ville Anonen",
      "birthday": "2000-03-28",
      "address": "Hämeentie 1",
      "zipcode": "00510",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358508660702",
      "email": "ville.anonen@testing.fi",
      "courses": [1]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Tapani Kumpu",
      "birthday": "1999-05-28",
      "address": "Jokukatu 17",
      "zipcode": "00560",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358502330702",
      "email": "tapani.kumpu@testing.fi",
      "courses": [1]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Milla Moilanen",
      "birthday": "1989-07-21",
      "address": "Testikatu 3",
      "zipcode": "00720",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358501750702",
      "email": "milla.moilanen@testing.fi",
      "courses": [2]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Maria Manninen",
      "birthday": "2002-09-28",
      "address": "Vilhonkatu 12",
      "zipcode": "00800",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358509890702",
      "email": "maria.manninen@testing.fi",
      "courses": [2, 3]
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Konsta Koistinen",
      "birthday": "2003-010-20",
      "address": "Pasilan raitti 21",
      "zipcode": "00100",
      "city": "Helsinki",
      "phone": "+358504760702",
      "email": "konsta.koistinen@testing.fi",
      "courses": [1, 3]
    }

  ],
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Gymnastics 1",
      "startdate": "2020-01-01",
      "enddate": "2020-02-10"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Gymnastics 2",
      "startdate": "2020-01-01",
      "enddate": "2020-02-10"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Fitness 1",
      "startdate": "2020-02-01",
      "enddate": "2020-02-20"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Dance 1",
      "startdate": "2020-05-01",
      "enddate": "2020-05-02"
    }
  ]
}
```

**This is my express server with Rest API**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const student = require("./models/student");
const course = require("./models/course");
//app middlewear
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //body Parser

//Connect to db
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected!"))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

//student

app.get("/students", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await student
      .find()
      .populate("course")
      .select("name birthday address zipcode city phone email")
      .then(docs => {
        const response = {
          count: docs.length,
          students: docs
        };
        res.json(response);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.get("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    student
      .findById(id)
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.put("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const update = {};
  for (const datas of req.body) {
    update[datas.updateData] = datas.value;
  }
  try {
    student
      .update({ _id: id }, { $set: update })
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.delete("/students/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    student
      .remove({ _id: id })
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/students", async (req, res, next) => {
  const logs = new student({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    birthday: req.body.birthday,
    address: req.body.address,
    zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
    city: req.body.city,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    email: req.body.email,
    course: req.body.courseid
  });
  logs
    .save()
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
//course
app.get("/courses", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await course
      .find()
      .select("name  student startdate enddate")

      .then(docs => {
        const response = {
          count: docs.length,
          courses: docs
        };
        res.json(response);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.get("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    course
      .findById(id)
      .select("name  student startdate enddate")
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.put("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const update = {};
  for (const datas of req.body) {
    update[datas.updateData] = datas.value;
  }
  try {
    course
      .update({ _id: id }, { $set: update })
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.delete("/courses/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  try {
    course
      .remove({ _id: id })
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.post("/courses", async (req, res, next) => {
  const logs = new course({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    startdate: req.body.startdate,
    enddate: req.body.enddate
  });
  logs
    .save()
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(` App is listening at port ${port}!`));
```

**This is my student Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const studentModel = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  birthday: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  zipcode: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  course: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Course",
    required: true
  }
});

const student = mongoose.model("Student", studentModel);
module.exports = student;
```

**This is course Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const courseModel = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  startdate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  enddate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
});

const course = mongoose.model("Course", courseModel);
module.exports = course;
```

[duplicate result visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCzdw.png)

Comment: Juha all of your student have _id which act as a primary key. You should prevent dublicate _id instead.

Comment: can you show me by code @eli

Comment: Juha i have changed my mind and consider to use email as primary key as Rahul suggested below since we can have two people with different same name but each with unique email.

Comment: But still, it prevents me, when I post the same person with different course :(. Did you guys get what I want :D

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplicate name data.
I suggest to make email as unique because two persons can have the same name but they always have a unique email.

Modify your student schema as given below.

`const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const {Schema} = mongoose;
    const studentModel = new Schema({
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        birthday: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        zipcode: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        course: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Course",
            required: true
        }
    });
    const student = mongoose.model("Student", studentModel);
    module.exports = student;`

Comment: for subscribing, multiple courses to student course should be an array in student schema